# Partial classes in Typescript. Is it possible?

Tags: typescript

In Angular source there is a [Validators](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/1d9d02696eadbee2c2f719e432efca22f1e494e9/packages/forms/src/validators.ts) class that starts as follows:

```
export class Validators {
  
  static min(min: number): ValidatorFn {
    return minValidator(min);
  }

  // ...

}
```

Is it possible to create another class on my application with the same name?

```
export class Validators {
  
  static dark(color: string): ValidatorFn {
    return darkValidator(color);
  }

  // ...

}
```

I would like to use both `min` and `dark` validators using:

```
Validators.min(2);
Validators.dark('#FFF');
```

In C#, for example, I could use `partial class`.

Comment: It's possible only when they are in the same file, which makes it a lot different than C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have `partial class` and therefore neither does TypeScript, as it would have an effect at runtime and is therefore not aligned with TypeScript's design goals (see [TypeScript Design Goal #8](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#goals), "avoid adding expression-level syntax" and [TypeScript Design Non-Goal #6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals), "provide additional runtime functionality").  There was a suggestion for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#563](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/563) but it was declined as out of scope: such a feature would need to exist in JavaScript before TypeScript would support it.

Instead of `partial class`, you could use [monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching) to add behavior to the `Validators` class from Angular.  Right now you only seem to be asking about `static` methods.  Since `static` methods are essentially the same as a property on the `Validators` class constructor itself, you can just add a `dark` property that does what you want.  In JavaScript that would look like this:

```
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';        
Validators.dark = function(color) {
  return darkValidator(color);
};
Validators.min(2); // okay
Validators.dark('#FFF'); // okay
```

In order for this to work in TypeScript, you need to do some [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to convince the compiler that `Validators` has a static `dark` method.  There is an open suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#2957](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2957) to allow some easy way of doing this for the static side of classes (the instance side is a bit easier), but for now the available solution is to declare a `namespace` with an exported variable named `dark` of the right type:

```
import { Validators, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
    
declare module '@angular/forms' {
  export namespace Validators {
    export let dark: (this: typeof Validators, color: string) => ValidatorFn;
  }
}

Validators.dark = function(color: string): ValidatorFn {
  return darkValidator(color);
};

Validators.min(2); // okay
Validators.dark('#FFF'); // okay
```

The `declare module` is [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) that lets you add typings to the imported `'@angular/forms'` module.  We've told the compiler that that the exported value named `Validators` is a namespace in addition to being a class constructor.  This lets you assign and use `Validators.dark()` with no compiler warning.

[StackBlitz link to code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tnziex?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Great answer. Really clear and it helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to use this code having the `declare module ... ` and the `Validators.dark = function` in a TS file and then using `Validators.dark('#FFF')` on tother TS files? I am asking because I am having trouble with it .. I get the error `Property 'equal' does not exist on type 'typeof Validators'` when compiling on `Validators.dark('#FFF')`. But I even have autocomplete when. typing it on the Editor ...

Comment: If you could show me a [mcve], maybe via a web IDE link, I might be able to help; right now though I don't have much insight into what the issue is.

Comment: I created an [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-waegqh?file=src/main.ts) that reproduces the problem. It seems even if I am only using `Validators.dark('#FFF')` I still need to import the darkValidator function. And that solves the problem. Any way around this? Shouldn'd `darkValidation` function be available when I add `export` to it?

Comment: I just noticed that even with `import` it does compile but when running I get the error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _angular_forms__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.Validators.dark is not a function. (In '_angular_forms__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.Validators.dark

Comment: There are apparently all kinds of drawbacks to trying to augment a module in another module; see [microsoft/TypeScript#12607](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12607) and issues to which it links.  I don't know if there's a canonical way to deal with this.  You could try to re-export your modified `Validators` and use that instead, like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cxjudz?file=src%2Fmain.ts), so you're no longer pretending you're targeting the "base" `Validators` anymore.